# Good Namespace Naming Conventions

Tags: language-agnostic, namespaces, theory

I am creating a class library for a CRUD business application. The major "categories" of business objects (with related data access layer objects) are:

- Maintenance (for working with master
  tables (master lists) in the database
- Incidents (most objects relate to a real-world incident)
- Search (obvious)

As of now, my namespaces are set up as follows:

- BusinessObjects.Maintenance.Contacts
- BusinessObjects.Maintenance.Products
- BusinessObjects.Maintenance.Classifications
- .
- BusinessObjects.Incidents.Contacts
- BusinessObjects.Incidents.Products
- BusinessObjects.Incidents.Classifications
- .
- BusinessObjects.Search.Contacts
- BusinessObjects.Search.Products
- BusinessObjects.Search.Classifications
- .
- Dal.Maintenance.Contacts
- Dal.Maintenance.Products
- Dal.Maintenance.Classifications
- .
- Dal.Incidents.Contacts
- Dal.Incidents.Products
- Dal.Incidents.Classifications
- .
- Dal.Search.Contacts
- Dal.Search.Products

Notice that every class ends up with the same name.

**Is this good form?**

**Are there any issues that can arise from this namespace convention? Any possible confusion to another person looking/using this code?**

I do realize that in the form code, one drawback will be that I will have to qualify all objects with the namespace. To me, that isn't a big deal. I usually prefer a little explicit-ity, if that's a word.

Comment: I think you want the word "explicitness". :)

Comment: I prefer to use "Core" instead of "BusinessObjects" for simplicity sake

Comment: Good idea. I'll change that to shorten the namespace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems Ok to me anyway. I would stay away from abbreviations though, that would get confusing and force people to have to know the abbreviations or look them up. Also they become unreadable and unspeakable.

```
"Lets take a look at the BusObjConfIntContYYYYmmdd package now..."
```

One issue you might run into is names with subtle differences. With length of names being a possible issue, your eyes might gloss over the whole thing and pick up only part of it. Would there ever be a case where this happened?:

```
BusinessObjects.Incidents.Classifications
BusinessObjects.Classifications.Incidents
```

or

```
BusinessObjects.Forms.ProjectManager.Exportable.Windows.XP
BusinessObjects.Forms.ProductManager.Exportable.Windows.XP
```

That contrived example might become a problem.

Answer (score 5):

It's generally a good idea to not name your packages after any specific pattern implemented but rather the business or functional domain they belong to.

ie:

```
Org.MyCompany.BusinessObjects.Maintenance.Contacts
Org.MyCompany.BusinessObjects.Incidents.Contacts
Org.MyCompany.BusinessObjects.Search.Contacts
```

instead:

```
Org.MyCompany.Contacts
```

which would contain classes/interfaces/objects/whatever that perform operations on "Contacts".

Comment: I had that originally, but another question of mine on SO determined that I should split maintenance functionality into a separate class all together from the classes representing (different but similar) objects belonging to Incidents.

Answer (score 2):

I think the project would benefit from a bit of abbreviation. When I've encountered problems like this in the past, I typically devote a bit of documentation to explaining a few abbreviations that serve as the namespaces. I usually restrict these shortened names to 3-5 characters. Not only does that add to general code readability in the form code, but I've also found that the shorter names lead to less confusion from other coders.

I hope that helps. At the end of the day, it really just depends on your team's preferences...

Answer (score 1):

After going through this a lot, we try to keep the number of namespaces low (less than a few dozen for a very large project), and the depth of the namespaces short (less than 5 or so). From a consumption standpoint (developers using our codebase), it is an overhead with very little benefit to have to keep track of a large number of namespaces with few classes in them.

We also group like with like, based on usage. If a developer is fairly likely to always use certain classes in conjunction with others, even though (in your example) one may be related to Maintenance and the other not, if they are logically, operationally or procedurally related we put them in the same namespace. The functionality that is separate (for example, maintenance-specific logic) is broken into another namespace using a provider model. Since a developer is less likely to need to modify the provider-contained functionality, that goes in a deeper, separate namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Your namespace hierarchy looks similar to a condition called nested generalization.  This is when you have classes which derive multiple different ways.

Imagine a class hierarchy as follows:

```
class Vehicle 

class Car : Vehicle
class CarRed : Car 
class CarBlue : Car 

class Truck : Vehicle 
class TruckRed : Truck 
class TruckBlue : Truck
```

Note that vehicles can be either cars or trucks.  Also, vehicles can be either red or blue.  This works perfectly well, but there is a problem when you want to add a new color, or vehicle type, because the burden of modification grows quadratically.

This problem is described by the GOF design patterns book -- Specifically the Bridge pattern.

Although it doesn't specifically address the concerns about namespaces, my instinct tells me that the situations are similar.  I would say, if you can avoid this, then you should.

Answer (score 1):

Also have a look at this MSDN article for guidelines for naming Namespaces

> Names of Namespaces: 
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229026.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I use one namespace per library and one per executable source code set. The names are always short. For example, in the executable I'm currently working on, I have:

- ALib   - my general utility library
- Mongo  - my mini web server library
- DBLite - my SQLite3 wrapper & simple
  persistence layer
- Track1 - executable (actually a
  couple of executables)

This seems to work pretty well. I find that very complex namespace schemes should be avoided, in the same way that very complex, deep class heirarchies should.