# Interesting Namespace Examples

Tags: .net, namespaces

Namespaces in .NET are meant to

- Group logical pieces of code together
- Prevent conflicts caused by use of common names

That said it's fairly open for doing naming that is interesting, funny or just different.

Do you have any examples of these different names?

I am not looking for [Good namespace naming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587341/good-namespace-naming-conventions) - rather the fun or different side, even if it goes against proven practices.

Comment: I'm out of votes, otherwise I'd be voting to close, as this question has little value. Namespaces aren't supposed to be fun! :)

Comment: What do you mean, they aren't supposed to be fun? Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those! Not in .NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of one I saw was everyone in the team had their own namespace, for example:

- Company.Product.Jim
- Company.Product.Bob

When I asked about this, it was so they could track who did what and prevent conflicts when checking in.

Comment: Hehe, that's a funny use for a namespace. They should go for a CVS if they want to track who did what and when! :)

Comment: That is quite possibly the worst example of namespace usage I've seen. Merge is your friend.

Comment: This example didn't happen to come from TheDailyWTF.com, did it?

Comment: OMG, are you serious? who came up with that idea?!