# Best Practices - WPF Custom Control Library - Organizing files, folders and namespaces

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, namespaces, projects-and-solutions

So I have a WPF custom control library with a few controls.

Some of the controls are quite complex and need multiple files stuffed into their own folders. Namespaces also imitate the folder structure, so I have namespaces like SomeControl.SomeControl etc. Some controls are trivial with just one file in the top level folder. I think its all really ugly but I don't know whats not!

Any rule of thumbs when organizing a custom control library both folders and namespaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Namespaces should not be named based on folder hierarchy but based on there functionality etc. -

> The name chosen for a namespace should
>   indicate the functionality made
>   available by types in the namespace

have a look at this MSDN article for guidelines for naming Namespaces

> Names of Namespaces: 
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229026.aspx

Other similar questions on SO -

[namespace naming conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918894/namespace-naming-conventions)

[Good Namespace Naming Conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587341/good-namespace-naming-conventions)